# Spark Error:expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe in Spark in which one of the columns contains an array.Now,I have written a separate UDF which converts the array to another array with distinct values in it only. See example below:

Ex: **[24,23,27,23]** should get converted to **[24, 23, 27]**
Code:

```
def uniq_array(col_array):
    x = np.unique(col_array)
    return x
uniq_array_udf = udf(uniq_array,ArrayType(IntegerType()))

Df3 = Df2.withColumn("age_array_unique",uniq_array_udf(Df2.age_array))
```

In the above code, `Df2.age_array` is the array on which I am applying the UDF to get a different column `"age_array_unique"` which should contain only unique values in the array.

However, as soon as I run the command `Df3.show()`, I get the error:

> net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)

Can anyone please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: aside: for anyone looking to sum arrays that get similar errors (in pyspark): u_sum = udf(lambda x: sum(x.tolist())). Here x can be a VectorUDT. Posting here as searching for that error yields this page as the first result.

Answer (score 78):

The source of the problem is that object returned from the UDF doesn't conform to the declared type. `np.unique` not only returns `numpy.ndarray` but also converts numerics to the corresponding `NumPy` types [which are not compatible](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12157) with `DataFrame` API. You can try something like this:

```
udf(lambda x: list(set(x)), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

or this (to keep order)

```
udf(lambda xs: list(OrderedDict((x, None) for x in xs)), 
    ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

instead.

If you really want `np.unique` you have to convert the output:

```
udf(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: `numpy` messed me up too. Personally, I was using `hypot`, `radians`, and `cos`, all of which are also available in `math`, whose versions don't have this problem, so I simply switched `from numpy` to `from math`

Comment: 2022 and this is still relevant FYI

Answer (score 11):

You need to convert the final value to a python list. You implement the function as follows:

```
def uniq_array(col_array):
    x = np.unique(col_array)
    return list(x)
```

This is because Spark doesn't understand the numpy array format. In order to feed a python object that Spark DataFrames understand as an `ArrayType`, you need to convert the output to a python `list` before returning it.

Answer (score 5):

I also got this error when my UDF returns a float but I forget to cast it as a float.  I need to do this:

```
retval = 0.5
return float(retval)
```

Comment: I got the error "expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)" , and fix it in this way

Comment: So spark udf must return a primitive data type, not a data type from numpy?

Answer (score 1):

As of pyspark version 2.4, you can use array_distinct transformation.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct

Answer (score 1):

**Below Works fine for me**

```
udf(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x.item() for x in <any numpy array>]
```

converts it to plain python.