# Is it possible to store a numpy array in a Spark Dataframe Column?

Tags: numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `dataframe` and I apply a function to it. This function returns an `numpy array` the code looks like this:

```
create_vector_udf = udf(create_vector, ArrayType(FloatType()))
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('vector', create_vector_udf('text'))
dmoz_spark_df.select('lang','url','vector').show(20)
```

Now spark seems not to be happy with this and does not accept `ArrayType(FloatType())`
I get the following error message:
`net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)`

I could just `numpyarray.tolist()` and return a list version of it, but obviously I would always have to recreate the `array` if I want to use it with `numpy`.

so is there a way to store a `numpy array`  in a `dataframe` `column`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Error:expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray.\_reconstruct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor)

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem is that object returned from the UDF doesn't conform to the declared type. `create_vector` must be not only returning `numpy.ndarray` but also must be converting numerics to the corresponding NumPy types which are not compatible with DataFrame API.

The only option is to use something like this:

```
udf(lambda x: create_vector(x).tolist(), ArrayType(FloatType()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest transforming the numpy arrays to dense `Vectors` with `VectorsUDT`, so the code will look like below:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT

arrayUDF = udf(lambda array: Vectors.dense(array)),VectorUDT())

df = df.withColumn('pyspark_arrays', arrayUDF(F.col('vector')))
```

to transform back to numpy arrays, using `.toArray()` is possible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is if you convert each row of the numpy array in DataFrame to list of integer.

```
df.col_2 = df.col_2.map(lambda x: [int(e) for e in x])
```

Then, convert it to Spark DataFrame directly

```
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df_spark.select('col_1', explode(col('col_2')).alias('col_2')).show(14)
```