# pyspark. zip arrays in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark DataFrame:

```
+------+----------------+
|    id|          data  |
+------+----------------+
|     1|    [10, 11, 12]|
|     2|    [20, 21, 22]|
|     3|    [30, 31, 32]|
+------+----------------+
```

At the end, I want to have the following DataFrame

```
+--------+----------------------------------+
|    id  |          data                    |
+--------+----------------------------------+
| [1,2,3]|[[10,20,30],[11,21,31],[12,22,32]]|
+--------+----------------------------------+
```

I order to do this. First I extract the data arrays as follow:

```python
tmp_array = df_test.select("data").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
a0 = tmp_array[0]
a1 = tmp_array[1]
a2 = tmp_array[2]
samples = zip(a0, a1, a2)
samples1 = sc.parallelize(samples)
```

In this way, I have in samples1 an RDD with the content

```
[[10,20,30],[11,21,31],[12,22,32]]
```

- Question 1: Is that a good way to do it?
- Question 2: How to include that RDD back into the dataframe?

Comment: Does your dataframe only have 2 rows?

Comment: Usually I have more than 2

Comment: Ok and so you want to get back just one row? The length of `data` is a constant right (I don't see how it works otherwise)?

Comment: The length of `data` could be different, but for now I will consider that is a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to get your desired output without serializing to `rdd` or using a `udf`. You will need two constants:

- The number of rows in your DataFrame (`df.count()`)
- The length of data (given)

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.array()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array) in a double list comprehension to pick out the elements of `"data"` in the order you want using [`pyspark.sql.Column.getItem()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
dataLength = 3
numRows = df.count()
df.select(
    f.collect_list("id").alias("id"),
    f.array(
        [
            f.array(
                [f.collect_list("data").getItem(j).getItem(i) 
                 for j in range(numRows)]
            ) 
            for i in range(dataLength)
        ]
    ).alias("data")
)\
.show(truncate=False)
#+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|id       |data                                                                          |
#+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[1, 2, 3]|[WrappedArray(10, 20, 30), WrappedArray(11, 21, 31), WrappedArray(12, 22, 32)]|
#+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `udf` function for the zip function but before that you will have to use `collect_list` function

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def zipUdf(array):
    return zip(*array)

zipping = f.udf(zipUdf, t.ArrayType(t.ArrayType(t.IntegerType())))

df.select(
    f.collect_list(df.id).alias('id'), 
    zipping(f.collect_list(df.data)).alias('data')
).show(truncate=False)
```

which would give you

```python
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id       |data                                                                          |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[WrappedArray(10, 20, 30), WrappedArray(11, 21, 31), WrappedArray(12, 22, 32)]|
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Usually I have more than 2. Thanks

Comment: You can generalize this to more than 2 rows by changing your udf to `return zip(*array)`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I hope you don't mind, but I edited the answer to just have the final answer, which works for all cases.

Comment: I wanted to do it this way as well but I wanted to put your name so I just added in it @pault thanks a lot

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have the following error: 
`net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for builtins.iter)`
Do you know what could be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor should help you

Comment: it means that you are returning an iterator from udf function which doesn't match with the declared datatype