# How to pass SparseVectors to `mllib` in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, sparse-matrix, apache-spark-mllib

I am using pyspark 1.6.3 through Zeppelin with python 3.5.

I am trying to implement Latent Dirichlet Allocation using the pyspark `CountVectorizer` and `LDA` functions. First, the problem: here is the code I am using. Let `df` be a spark dataframe with tokenized text in a column 'tokenized'

```
vectors = 'vectors'
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol = 'tokenized', outputCol = vectors)
model = cv.fit(df)
df = model.transform(df)

corpus = df.select(vectors).rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]]).cache()
ldaModel = LDA.train(corpus, k=25)
```

This code is taken more or less from the [pyspark api docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda).
On the call to `LDA` I get the following error:

```
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.sql.types._create_row)
```

The [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor) tells me that this is due to a type mismatch.

So lets look at the types for `LDA` and from `CountVectorizer`. From spark docs here is another [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.LDAModel) of a sparse vector going into `LDA`:

```
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, SparseVector
>>> data = [
...     [1, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0])],
...     [2, SparseVector(2, {0: 1.0})],
... ]
>>> rdd =  sc.parallelize(data)
>>> model = LDA.train(rdd, k=2, seed=1)
```

I implement this myself and this is what `rdd` looks like:

```
>> testrdd.take(2)

[[1, DenseVector([0.0, 1.0])], [2, SparseVector(2, {0: 1.0})]]
```

On the other hand, if I go to my original code and look at `corpus` the rdd with the output of `CountVectorizer`, I see (edited to remove extraneous bits):

```
>> corpus.take(3)

[[0, Row(vectors=SparseVector(130593, {0: 30.0, 1: 13.0, ...
 [1, Row(vectors=SparseVector(130593, {0: 52.0, 1: 44.0, ...
 [2, Row(vectors=SparseVector(130593, {0: 14.0, 1: 6.0, ...
]
```

So the example I used (from the docs!) doesn't produce a tuple of (index, SparseVector), but a (index, Row(SparseVector))... or something?

Questions:

- Is the Row wrapper around the SparseVector what is causing this error?
- If so, how do I get rid of the Row object? Row is a property of a df, but I used `df.rdd` to convert to an rdd; what else would I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe the problem. Just extract `vectors` from the `Row` object.

```
corpus = df.select(vectors).rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]['vectors']]).cache()
```