# "expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)" when calling UDF that returns FloatType()

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I believe it is related to this one: [Spark Error:expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor)

I have a dataframe

```
id col_1 col_2
1 [1,2] [1,3]
2 [2,1] [3,4]
```

I want to create another column that is a `cosine` distance between `col_1` and `col_2`.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

def cosine_distance(a,b):
    try:
        return cosine(a, b)
    except Exception as e:
        return 0.0 # in case division by zero
```

And I defined a `udf`:

`cosine_distance_udf = udf (cosine_distance, FloatType())`

And finally:

`new_df = df.withColumn('cosine_distance', cosine_distance_udf('col_1', 'col_2'))`

And I have the error: `PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What if you do `return float(cosine(a, b))`?

Comment: @coldspeed Unbelievable it works well. Many thanks.

Comment: I've written an example and explained why. Also, this may be a duplicate but I don't think it is a duplicate of that particular question, @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz

Comment: @coldspeed seems you're right - I removed the close vote

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason for the error is clear when you check the return type of `cosine`:

```
type(cosine([1, 2], [1, 3]))
# numpy.float64
```

However, `np.float64` is a subclass of `float`:

```
issubclass(np.float64, float)
# True
```

So, with a small change, to your function,

```
def cosine_distance(a, b):
    try:
        return float(cosine(a, b)) # cosine(a, b).item()
    except Exception as e:
        return 0.0 # in case division by zero
```

This will work

```
df.withColumn('cosine_distance', cosine_distance_udf('col_1', 'col_2')).show()

+------+------+---------------+
| col_1| col_2|cosine_distance|
+------+------+---------------+
|[1, 2]|[3, 4]|     0.01613009|
|[2, 1]|[3, 4]|     0.10557281|
+------+------+---------------+
```