# Calculate cosine similarity between two columns of Spark DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame with two columns containing **PySpark SparseVectors**.

And I have to calculate a pairwise cosine similarity between them.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, HashingTF, IDF

phrases = ['I have a few texts here',
           'This is a text number one',
           'This is a text number two']

schema = StructType(fields=[
    StructField('col1', IntegerType()),
    StructField('col2', StringType())
])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(1, len(phrases) + 1), 'col2': phrases}), schema=schema)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='col2', outputCol='words')
df2 = tokenizer.transform(df)

tf_hasher = HashingTF(numFeatures=15, binary=True, inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol='tf_vector')
df3 = tf_hasher.transform(df2)

idf = IDF(inputCol=tf_hasher.getOutputCol(), outputCol='tf_idf_vector')
idf_model = idf.fit(df3)
df4 = idf_model.transform(df3)

left = df4[['col1', 'col2', 'tf_idf_vector']].withColumnRenamed('col1', 'col1_1')\
    .withColumnRenamed('col2', 'col2_1')\
    .withColumnRenamed('tf_idf_vector', 'tf_idf_vector_1')

right = df4[['col1', 'col2', 'tf_idf_vector']].withColumnRenamed('col1', 'col1_2')\
    .withColumnRenamed('col2', 'col2_2')\
    .withColumnRenamed('tf_idf_vector', 'tf_idf_vector_2')

df5 = left.crossJoin(right)

def cosine_similarity(u, v):
    return v.dot(u) / (v.norm(2) * u.norm(2))

cosine_similarity_udf = f.udf(cosine_similarity, FloatType())

df6 = df5.withColumn('cosine_similarity', cosine_similarity_udf(df5.tf_idf_vector_1, df5.tf_idf_vector_2))
df6.show(10)
```

I expect the following result (like, if I calculated in Pandas):

[image]
But actually I get an error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o871.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1078 in stage 88.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1078.3 in stage 88.0 (TID 21038, executor 23): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
```

Spark version is 2.4.4. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Error:expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray.\_reconstruct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor)